# Want ListBoxDragDropTarget.AllowDrag = True //not AllowDrop

Tags: silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have a collection of controls displayed in a ListBoxDragDropTarget.  It works great when I want the user to be able to drag and drop between listboxes.  But my app has a mode where the dragging is disabled and during that mode clicking on a listboxitem should fire a command.

I think the ListBoxDragDropTarget is stealing the mouse button events...  Hence the title of this question.  FWIW, Google turned up some work arounds that derive from ListBoxDragDropTarget and override and cancel some of the eventing.  I don't think that will work here because I think the event.cancel=true is the problem in the first place.

Any ideas?  My goal is to support two modes:
1) Dragging the listboxitem between two listboxes
2) Clicking the listboxitem invokes a command

I am running SL4